# Why does as.character() return an integer on a list of dates?

Tags: r, string, date

I was surprised to observe the following behavior in R:

```
as.character(c(Sys.Date()))
#> [1] "2018-02-05"

as.character(list(Sys.Date()))
#> [1] "17567"
```

Why does this happen?  That is, clearly the "17567" is the result of `as.integer(Sys.Date)`, but I do not follow the logic for why `as.character(list(Sys.Date()))` should wind up invoking `as.integer()`.

(Usually strings being treated as integers can be blamed on not setting
`options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, but that doesn't appear to be the case here.)

**EDIT**: As Josh observes, this is due to the underlying behavior of as.vector, but I do not find that any more intuitive:

```
as.vector(Sys.Date())
#> 17567
as.vector(Sys.Date(), "character")
#> "17567"
```

Why? (Yes, I believe dates are stored as integers in the lower-level internals, but this coercion to a literal integer in this circumstance without a warning seems surprising to me).

Also this manifests in more subtle ways:

```
tbl <- tibble:::as_data_frame(list(col1 = list(Sys.Date(), "stuff")))
df <- as.data.frame(tbl)
df
#>    col1
#> 1 17567
#> 2 stuff

df[1, 1]
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "2018-02-05"
```

Note that the print method for `data.frame` is showing the date as an integer, when in fact it is a list column and the date is still the date.

It's not clear what is going on with the print method in this case, and why it shows such a misleading representation of the data.

**EDIT**:

Other examples where Date class surprisingly falls off, exposing underlying numeric base type:

```
vapply(list(Sys.Date()), I, Sys.Date())
vapply(list(Sys.Date()), lubridate::as_date, Sys.Date())
```

and my favorite so far:

```
unlist(list(Sys.Date()))
```

It appears that vector operations with `Date` (and POSIX objects) are fragile; one should focus on the `mode` / `typeof` and not `class` to anticipate how the vector will behave.

Comment: fyi `typeof(Sys.Date())` gives `"double"`, not integer

Comment: `as.character(c(Sys.Date()))` invokes `as.character.Date` whereas `as.character(list(Sys.Date()))`invokes `as.character.default` which starts with `unclass(Sys.Date()) = 17567`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue ultimately has to do with the behavior of the function `as.vector()`.

When you apply `as.character()` to a list, it sees an object of class `"list"` (not one of class `"Date"`). Since there is no `as.character()` method for lists, the default method `as.character.default` gets dispatched. Its does the following:

```
as.character.default
# function (x, ...) 
# .Internal(as.vector(x, "character"))
# <bytecode: 0x0000000006793e88>
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

As you can see, it first prepares the data object by coercing it to a vector. Running `as.vector()` directly on a list of Date objects shows, in turn, that it is what is producing the coercion to integer and then to character.

```
as.vector(list(Sys.Date()), "character")
# [1] "17567"
```

---

As Carl points out, the explanation above, even if accurate, is not really  satisfying. A more complete answer requires looking at what happens under the hood, in the C code executed by the call to `.Internal(as.vector(x, "character"))`. All of the relevant C code is in the source file [coerce.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/coerce.c).

First up is [`do_asvector()`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/coerce.c#L1466) which calls [`ascommon()`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/coerce.c#L1532) which calls [`coerceVector()`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/coerce.c#L1357) which calls [`coerceVectorList()`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/coerce.c#L1050) and then, finally, [`coerceToString()`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/coerce.c#L1050). `coerceToString()` [examines the "typeof"](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/coerce.c#L757) the element it is processing, and in our case, seeing that it is a "REAL" switches to [this code block](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/coerce.c#L770-L778):

```
case REALSXP:
PrintDefaults();
savedigits = R_print.digits; R_print.digits = DBL_DIG;/* MAX precision */
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
//  if ((i+1) % NINTERRUPT == 0) R_CheckUserInterrupt();
    SET_STRING_ELT(ans, i, StringFromReal(REAL(v)[i], &warn));
}
R_print.digits = savedigits;
break;
```

And why does it use the block for objects of with a typeof `REALSXP`? Because that's the storage mode of R `Date` objects (as can be seen by doing `mode(Sys.Date())` or `typeof(Sys.Date())`).

---

The take-home is this: In the chain of events described above, the elements of the list are not somehow caught and treated as a `"Date"` objects while in the realm of R function calls and method dispatch. Instead, they get passed along as a `"list"` (aka `VECSXP`) to a series of C functions. And at that point, it's kind of too late, as the C functions that process that list know nothing about the `"Date"` class of its elements. In particular, the function that ultimately does the conversion to character, `coerceToCharacter()` only sees the elements' storage mode, which is REAL/numeric/double, and processes them as if that was **all** that they were.

Comment: You can avoid the coercion by extracting the element(s) from the list yourself with `as.character(list(Sys.Date())[[1]])` or `sapply(list(Sys.Date()), as.character)`.

Comment: Thanks, but this still begs the question: `as.vector(Sys.Date(), "character")` returns an integer (coerced to character).  Why?  By what logic?  (I get that internally dates are stored as integers, but this seems odd / bug-like behavior....

Comment: @cboettig OK, I finally got a moment, and continued tracking the conversion down into the world of C functions that get dispatched by the call to `.Internal()`. The details, though, aren't what really matter. The final paragraph is my best shot at an answer to what I think your real question is.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve what you want with the function`format` as in

```
format(Sys.Date(), "%a %b %d")
```

`Sys.Date` gives a `Date` object and there are many ways to convert that to a string, so a special function is due. `format` will give you a character representation of your `Date`.

BTW: If you just hit Sys.Date() on the console, this will invoke `print.Date` which internally uses `format` as well, as you can see by typing `print.Date` without brackets `()` at the console.

Answer (score 0):

`paste` function is a great work-around solution.

```
paste(rep(lubridate::as_datetime(0), 2))
# [1] "1970-01-01" "1970-01-01"
```

[base::paste](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/paste) converts its arguments (via as.character) to character strings, and concatenates them (separating them by the string given by sep). If the arguments are vectors, they are concatenated **term-by-term** to give a character vector result. Vector arguments are recycled as needed, with zero-length arguments being recycled to "".

If you have a list of POSIXct objects, for example,

```
l.ex = list(t1 = lubridate::as_datetime(0), t2 = lubridate::as_datetime(100))
do.call(paste, l.ex)
[1] "1970-01-01 1970-01-01 00:01:40"
```

use `do.call` to avoid coercing.