# R 3.5.1 paste() containing integer64 corrupts values

Tags: r

I've been tracking down some "impossible" numbers in a report I've been generating via R and the `RPostgres` library.  The code is running many database queries, some of which happen to come back with `BIGINT` types (via SQL `COUNT()` aggregates) which `RPostgres` interprets as `integer64` by default (which I'm working around with the `bigint="integer"` option as none of my values are >2^31 at the moment).

I've managed to get a very minimal example:

```
i <- bit64::as.integer64(1)
paste(data.frame(a=i))
```

giving me `4.94065645841247e-324` back, instead of `1`.  I presume `paste()` is treating the `int64` as a `double`, but not sure why.

any suggestions?  mostly wondering if this is something strange on my system and if I should be reporting this upstream.

this is R 3.5.1 on an up-to-date arch-linux system and have just updated all packages

Comment: I think the key thing here is that you're calling `paste` on a data frame, not the individual value `i`.

Comment: If you parse it as numeric or integer it returns 1. `paste(data.frame(a=as.numeric(i)))` I haven't read enough to understand why sometimes factors are parsed weirdly on dataframes or else (it changes the value). I'm not saying this is the case but it can be related.

Comment: Yeah, it's the old `as.character` coercion of lists. There's probably an `as.character` method for integer64, but when it's in a list R can't coerce it cleanly.

Comment: You could use: `paste(data.frame(a=as.character(i)))`

Comment: @ismirsehregal This isn't a duplicate of that question. If it's a duplicate it would be of a question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48631580/324364).

Comment: Yep, you are right - the direct link to `library(bit64)` was missing - removed the comment.

Comment: this issue is easy to work around; but it feels like a bug to me and I can't see why the current behaviour would be desirable

Comment: I understand the frustration, but it comes down to the fact that lists can in principle contain any type of object. You could argue, in fact, that `paste()` is sort of nonsensical on list objects, and that if you want to paste list elements together you should be handling the coercion to character explicitly, for safety.

Comment: You could argue that R should loop through each list element and coerce each individually in a way that will correctly call available S3 methods, but even if you do that, there's no assurance that such a method exists anyway, so you're back to needing the programmer to handle it explicitly to be totally safe.

Comment: I agree with @joran.  Check `paste(data.frame(a=i)$a)` or `lapply(data.frame(a=i), paste)` for reference.  The issue is not in `paste`.

Comment: The fundamental issue you're having is the same as what you see if you run `as.character(list(a = 1,b = c(2,3),c = c("a")))`, as another example.

Comment: I think I'm surprised when R knows this object's class and in some places "does the right thing" (i.e. `print()` displays the object's value as `1`) but other places picks a somewhat arbitrary string representation